# Roboflow Yolo: how to process multiple images and save individual return json?

Tags: python, json, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, roboflow

Below is a simple Roboflow Yolo segmentation code that I am running on **Colab**.
The pre-trained model works fine on 1 sample image. The only thing that matters here is the `model`, which is an instance segmentation model. The result of `prediction` returns labels and coordinates of detected objects in json format.

```
!pip install roboflow

rf = Roboflow(api_key="YOUR_PRIVATE_API_KEY")
workspace = rf.workspace("workspace-id")
project = workspace.project("model-id")
version = project.version("version-number")
model = version("version-number").model

prediction = model.predict("/content/sample 1.jpg")

# Plot the prediction
prediction.plot()

# Convert predictions to JSON
prediction.json()
```

But I have a hard time modifying the script.

**Question 1:** I searched and tried every code but still can not figure out how to save the return json file. Can you help me to add a code to save the json file(prediction in this case)to a specific location that has a same file name as input image?

**Question 2:** I simply dragged a sample image to content to test. And now I am trying to process every image in a google drive. I can link a specific folder using the below code, but how can make so all images on the drive can be processed automatically?

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
```

Comment: The sample prediction looks like this:
```{'predictions': [{'x': 489.5, 'y': 402.5, 'width': 81.0, 'height': 123.0, 'confidence': 0.9258119463920593, 'class': 'window', 'points': [{'x': 525.0, 'y': 461.0659091375009}, {'x': 478.0, 'y': 461.0255017558019}, {'x': 467.9470716481465, 'y': 457.0}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1 - updating the imgfile_location variable will update the image you predict on, and save the JSON file of the predictions with the corresponding file name:

```
from roboflow import Roboflow
from google.colab import files, drive
import os

def safe_create_path_parent(path: str) -> None:
path_parent = os.path.dirname(path)
os.makedirs(path_parent, exist_ok=True)

def dump_to_json(target_path: str, content: dict) -> None:
safe_create_path_parent(target_path)
with open(target_path, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(content, outfile, indent=4)

drive.mount(‘/gdrive’)

rf = Roboflow(api_key="YOUR_PRIVATE_API_KEY")
workspace = rf.workspace("workspace-id")
project = workspace.project("model-id")
version = project.version("version-number")
model = version("version-number").model

imgfile_location = "/content/sample 1.jpg"
imgfile_name = Path(imgfile_location).name
prediction = model.predict(imgfile_location)

# Plot the prediction
prediction.plot()

# Convert predictions to JSON
predicted_result = prediction.json()

# Save JSON predictions to your computer
dump_to_json(imgfile_name, predicted_result)
```

**EDIT: Question 2 - multiple images or a folder:**
raw_data_location = "INSERT_PATH_TO_IMG_DIRECTORY" for raw_data_extension in ['.jpg', '.jpeg', 'png']
globbed_files = glob.glob(raw_data_location + '/*' + raw_data_extension)
for img_path in globbed_files:
predictions = model.predict(img_path, confidence=40, overlap=30)
# save prediction image
predictions.save(f'inferenceResult_{os.path.basename(img_path)}')
predictions_json = predictions.json()
print(predictions_json)

Comment: Here is the Roboflow python package quick start documentation: https://docs.roboflow.com/python#quick-start